# Error in converting from markdown to editor in flask

Tags: python, flask, markdown

I am using markdown library in python to display some markdown in my flask app.
I am getting an error during display of the output as it is showing the markdown content without converting it to HTML.

This is my python code.

```
import markdown
from flask import Flask
#import some other libraries

@app.route('/md')
def md():
    content = """
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    Chapter
    =======

    Section
    -------

    * Item 1
    * Item 2
    **Ishaan**
    """

    content = Markup(markdown.markdown(content))
    return render_template('md.html', **locals())
```

This is my html code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Markdown Snippet</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

I am following the code from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/19/)

I know I am doing some blunder but I'll be thankful if anybody help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dedent your lines of Markdown.

Anything inside Python triple-quotes is interpreted by Python literally. That includes the indentation. Therefore, the text passed to Markdown is indented by one level causing Markdown to interpret the entire document as a code block. Remove the indentation and Markdown will recognize the text properly:

```
@app.route('/md')
def md():
    content = """
<h1>Hello</h1>
Chapter
=======

Section
-------

* Item 1
* Item 2
**Ishaan**
"""
```

Note that the example you are copying from also does not indent the triple-quoted text. Of course, that makes your Python code less readable. Therefore, the Python Standard Library includes the [textwrap.dedent()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) function, which will remove the indentation programmatically:

```
from textwrap import dedent

@app.route('/md')
def md():
    content = """
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    Chapter
    =======

    Section
    -------

    * Item 1
    * Item 2
    **Ishaan**
    """

    content = Markup(markdown.markdown(dedent(content))) # <= dedent here
```

Note that `content` is passed through `dedent` before being passed to Markdown.